# How do I correctly include a script on a locally hosted node server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I stripped down the problem to the bare minimum, here's the situation:

The most basic `index.html` possible, with no DOM elements and only one script, located in the same folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The simplest possible `script.js`, which is just a `console.log` statement:

```
console.log("%cI'm working!", "font: bold 17px arial; color: #3e9;");
```

a very simple `server.js`:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

const PORT = 3000;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(index);
}).listen(PORT);

console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
```

If I run the page locally, i.e. by launching `index.html` with my web browser, everything works fine, and I see the log in the console. If, instead, I try to launch the server using `node server.js`, I come across a very weird error in which `script.js` appears to contain the contents of `index.html`, resulting in a syntax error.

Here's a screenshot of DevTools for clarity:
[image: Screenshot of DevTools]

What causes this? How can I correctly include the script on my local server?

Comment: Your server responses all requests with `index.html`. You need a routing.

Comment: You should be serving the `index.html` file as it is rather than reading it in as a file and then writing it as a response. Or are you doing it this way for a reason?

Comment: @Craicerjack The reason is I'm a beginner and I'm basing my work on tutorials I find online, is there a better way to do that?

Comment: There normally is but a tutorial on node will go through that with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server responses all requests with `index.html`. You need a routing.

The most basic approach is

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');
var script = fs.readFileSync('script.js');

const PORT = 3000;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.path.endsWith('script.js')) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
    res.end(script);
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(index);
  }
}).listen(PORT);

console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
```

This should be only the first step to understand the basics. Usually you would use a framework like [Express](https://expressjs.com/) with a routing as described in https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html and serve static files as described in https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

An example with Express:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

But this will serve all files in your project root. You should restructure your project and move the files for your website into a separate folder, e.g. `public`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```